# record iphone screenat 30fps for itunes connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, quicktime

I need to record a video of my iphone screen to submit on itunes connect.
this video should be at 30fps.
When I try to record this video with quick time player I get a frame rate at 60fos
how can I do
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your video using tools like iMovie, Final Cut Pro or Adobe After Effects. Apple has an extensive guide on how to create you App Previews: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/

Here's for example the guide how to do it with iMovie: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/imovie/